# Dropdown, change and click events fire only the first time - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, button, drop-down-menu, mouseevent

Using jQuery 1.9.1 in a web page & making an AJAX call to return an XML dataset.  The data is loaded into rows in an HTML table.  The first 2 columns contain text information, the 3rd column can contain one of three things:  a Dropdown box, a Submit button, or Text.  The 4th column contains either a Submit button (on rows in which there's a dropdown) or are blank.

The HTML table is as follows:

```
<table id="ztable" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <thead id="zthead">
  </thead>
  <tbody id="ztbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The data is loaded to the table in a function that loops through row by row.

```
var trow = $("<tr class='rows'>"), tbdy=$("#ztbody");
.....
$(xml).find("Row").each(function(index) {
celldata = "<td class='msgTime'><div class='msgTime " + msgClass + "'>" + msgTime + "</div></td>" + 
....
"<td class='action'><div class='action " + msgClass + "'>"+ actionDD +"</div></td>" +
....
$(celldata).appendTo(trow);
trow.appendTo(tbdy);
```

When the page loads for the first time, all the mouse events, click events and change events all fire as they should.

However, once they have fired, I set a switch that forces a re-create of the HTML table.  Once that has executed though, the dropdowns are still there & can be opened, but nothing is selectable.  No buttons respond, no mouse events fire.

I'm calling the same function that I use to build the table the first time through, but use a `$("ztable tbody).empty()` to clear out what's there & re-create it.  I know when the table is re-created, that whatever processing I had done on the first table load has taken place & those rows no longer show, but the re-created table - which has the appropriate columns, dropdowns, buttons etc - will allow the dropdown to open (and an item can be selected), but nothing else fires - no mouse events, nothing.

What needs to happen in order to bind the controls to the re-created page?  Or is there something else I'm doing incorrectly?

*** *EDIT* *****

Per follow-up, I am editing & providing more info on the handlers.  All of these are in the `$(document).ready`:

```
$(".choices").mousedown(function() { console.log("mousedown"); })
$(".choices").mouseover(function() { console.log("mouseover"); })
$(".choices").mouseout(function() { console.log("mouseout"); })
$(".choices").mouseup(function() { console.log("mouseup"); })

....

$(".rows").each(function() {
    var $d = $(this).find(".choices");
    $d.change(function() {
        if ($d.val() > 0) {
            ..... do stuff where dropdown has been selected
         }
    });
});


$(".sBtn").click(function() {
   ..... do stuff where one type button was clicked
   });

$(".rbtn").click(function() {
    .... do stuff where another type button was clicked
   });
```

`.choices` is a class that is assigned to the `SELECT` dropdowns.
`.rows` is a class assigned to the rows in the `<tbody>` of `ztable`.
`.sBtn` is a class assigned to the button that would be in the 4th column & associated to a dropdown box in the 3rd column.
`.rbtn` is a class assigned to buttons that would be in the 3rd column.

Each of the buttons & dropdowns have an ID that is unique to each of them, for example:  `choice_M_40` & `sb_M_40` would be on row 1.  `choice_M_45` & `sb_M_45` would be on row 2. `rb_X_3000` would be in column 3 of row 3, etc.

Comment: I don't see any hanlder in your code. You need to delegate events

Comment: As above.  If you post your event handlers then we can help

Comment: please use **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)** to show your code clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are going to use dynamic content you need to bind delegate handlers rather than binding directly to an element. When you use `.on()` with a single argument or `.click()` or other events similarly you only bind event handlers to elements that currently exist in the DOM.

Use `.on()` with an extra argument to use delegate handlers which will capture events as they bubble up the DOM rather than binding to the element itself.

```
$(document).on('click','div.action',function(){
    //do your click programming here
})
```

is the most general form and will bind a delegate handler onto the document which will catch click events bubbling up from elements with selector `div.action`

In your situation it looks like `$("#ztbody")` is most likely static so you can bind your delegate handlers to that instead of the document to make your code more efficient.

```
$("#ztbody").on('click','div.action',function(){
    //do your click programming here
})
```

Do similarly for all your different events. The alternative is to rebind all your events every time you add or change your content i would not recommend that though.

Comment: thank you for your help.  I've been able to take some of what you suggested & adapt it to (now) catch dropdown open & clicks on DIV's.  I did have a follow-up question though.  The page uses `setTimeout` to recursively call the AJAX function that (eventually) reloads the table.  I had been using `$(".choices").mouseup/down/enter/leave` to issue a `clearTimeout` & kill the recursive timer, and set a new `setTimeout` variable to reload the table after X minutes (if no selection is made).  How do you then trap open/close of dropdowns via the `.on("click","div....` handlers?

Comment: accept this answer and open a new question detailing your new problem.